# Ember component keyboard event does not trigger

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Folloing the guide https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/components/handling-events/. I try to bind event handler for key event for a component but seems it does not work. I do not see an alert when I press a key; however, the `doubleClick` event handler can be triggered.

What I want to achive is to use key <kbd>1</kbd> to select the first radio button.

**Updated**

The event can only be triggered when the radio button has the focus.

**My Question**

is there a way to bind the keyboard event with out make particular control in focus?

**Code**

Component JS,

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['quiz-control'],

    keyUp(e) {
        alert(e.keyCode);
    },

    keyDown(e) {
        alert(e.keyCode);
    },

    keyPress(e) {
        alert(e.keyCode);
    }

});
```

Component HTML,

```
<input name="ans" type="radio" id="op0"/>
<label for="op0">1</label>

<input name="ans" type="radio" id="op1"/>
<label for="op1">2</label>

<input name="ans" type="radio" id="op2"/>
<label for="op2">3</label>

<input name="ans" type="radio" id="op3"/>
<label for="op3">4</label>
```

Comment: You can bind keyUp event for `document` instead of `Component`.

Comment: I am thinking to bind a vent to the comonent `$()` manually in `didInsertElement()` hook, instead of using Ember default component event handler or custom event. Do you think `customEvent` would be a better op?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bind the `keypress` event in `document`,

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['quiz-control'],

    didInsertElement() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        $(document).on('keypress', this._keypressHandler);
    },

    willDestroyElement() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        $(document).off('keypress', 'document', this._keypressHandler);
    },

    _keypressHandler(e) {
        console.log('quiz-control', e.keyCode);
    }
});
```

Comment: Works great for creating the listener, but I had to remove the handler function in `off()` in order to get the listener removed in `willDestroyElement`.